# Filtering rows by years

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have this code that is used for to filter rows by year. I know that you are supposed to call the method datetime for this code to work. Every answer I see on StackOverFlow contains code similar to mine and it works for them. How can I print the row values from 2017-2018 without running into errors? This is my entire code, do I need to create a function? I am very unfamiliar with datetime code so any insight or guide will be very beneficial, like I said I have been looking for answers for the past 2 days without any findings so I believe I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Please let me know If i need to clarify my question more.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


df = pd.read_csv('otd.csv', encoding='latin-1')
df['Delivery Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Delivery Date'], format= '%m/%d/%Y')
df[(df['Delivery Date'].year >= 2017) & (df['Delivery Date'].year <= 2018)]
print(df)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\khalha\eclipse-workspace\Test3\Project3\P3.py", line 10, in <module>
    df[(df['Delivery Date'].year >= 2017) & (df['Delivery Date'].year <= 2018)]
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'
```

otd.csv:

[image]

Comment: Please, add `odd.csv` example and received error.

Comment: Please, load example not as image, but as text. You can read about principles of  creating an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `.dt` accessor: [dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html)

```
df[(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year >= 2017) & (df['Delivery Date'].dt.year <= 2018)]
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)